# An array for different objects in java?

Tags: java

So, for example, let's say I have this class named for example "Animals", a subclass called "Dogs" and other one called "Cats" and a class for running the program.

```
class Animals{
    int size;
    String name;
}
class Dogs extends Animals{
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Woff");
    }
}

class Cats extends Animals{
    void meow(){
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

And in the class Test I want to create an array that holds both of them. How should I declare them so I can also access to their methods? I was thinking, for example, in something like this:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animals [] array = new Animals[2];
        array[0] = new Dogs();
        array[1] = new Cats();
        array[0].bark();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work that way since Java recognizes the method as a Animals' method.

Comment: As a good practice, your class should be called `Animal` not `Animals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `instanceof` to check wether the animal is a cat or a dog, then safe cast and call the good method :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Animals [] array = new Animals[2];
    array[0] = new Dogs();
    array[1] = new Cats();
    array[0].bark();
}

public static void makeSound(Animal[] animals){
    for(Animal a : animals){
        if(a instanceof Dogs){
            ((Dogs)a).bark();
        }else if(a instanceof Cats){
            ((Cats)a).meow();
        }
}
```

This will print :

```
Woff
Meow
```

---

Better practice :

```
class Animals{
    int size;
    String name;
    abstract void makeSound();
}
class Dogs extends Animals{
    void makeSound(){
        System.out.println("Woff");
    }
}

class Cats extends Animals{
    void makeSound(){
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Why doesn't this work

As the array is of animals it won't let you call the subclasses methods, as the compiler can't be sure any animal would have a bark or meow method.

## How to fix

You can do one of the following:

- Add an abstract makeSound method to animal, and use for both, so the compiler knows the method exists.
- Have 2 arrays, 1 of dogs and one of cats, so the compiler knows the method exists.
- Check the types of each item using instanceof and call the methods after casting to the right type, so the type is checked at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the instance of the object at the array position and after this it's safe to call the method by casting the object to the dogs class:

```
if(array[0] instanceof Dogs) {
    ((Dogs)array[0]).bark()
}
```